# Lens Distortion Nuke Nodes for Windows

Tags: batch-file

need to do : (env var "LENSMODEL_PATH" should point to the directory where the actual lens distortion model .dlls are located)

when I load nuke lens distortion..
Error : Unknown command (Unknown command while executing)

(tde4_ldp_classic_3de_mixed: Unknown command while executing "scriptReadFile $f" invoked from within "if [file isdirectory $f] { # load all images in this directory set ff [filename_list -compress $f] foreach t $ff { set fulln..." (procedure "drop" line 14) invoked from within "drop $drop_text")

Please correct this... 
****batch File script :

```
@echo off

:NUKE_VARIABLES
set NUKE_VER=6.3v8
set NUKE_PATH=C:\Program Files\Nuke6.3v8\%NUKE_VER%

:CUSTOM_VARIABLES
set NUKE_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Nuke6.3v8\%NUKE_VER%
set NUKE_PLUGINS=%NUKE_PATH%

:rem path to lensmodels
set LENSMODEL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Nuke6.3v8\plugins\%NUKE_VER% Console
echo Starting Nuke %NUKE_VER% ...
echo StartPath: %NUKE_INSTALL_PATH%
echo.%NUKE_INSTALL_PATH%\nuke6.3.exe" -m8 -V %*
```

Comment: So - do you have a question?

Comment: You should edit it into the question itself

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what language is producing the error you've reported. That would most likely be important.

However, your very last line contains unbalanced `"quotes"` - probably need one just before the first `%`.

Comment: these some installation step I could not follow... plz help MAGOO ------                                  Installation:
 copy "lensDistortion_3de.dll" to Nuke's plugin directory
 edit Nuke_6.2v2.bat according to your needs
 env var "LENSMODEL_PATH" should point to the directory where the actual lens distortion model .dlls are located
Example:
set LENSMODEL_PATH=C:\NukeTools\LensModels\ 
(Important: Note the "\" at the end of the path!)

Comment: .dlls file path : C:\Program Files\Nuke6.3v8\plugins\